# XSL: how do I keep xsltproc from tampering with an escaped HTML string in an attribute value?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am reading an XML file of flat entities where the values are all in attributes and trying to produce a delimited text file (CSV, but pipe not comma<sup>1</sup>).  The problem is that one of the attributes has, as a value, an arbitrary blob of HTML, which has (in the XML file) been properly escaped.  When I run xsltproc with my style sheet, though, I'm getting the HTML out, complete with line breaks which means my output is no longer one row per element.

Sample XML input -- this is all on one line in the source but I have inserted artificial line breaks here for legibility:

```
<row Id="-1" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2010-11-18T19:05:26.543" DisplayName="Community" 
  LastAccessDate="2010-11-18T19:05:26.543" Location="on the server farm" 
  AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Hi, I'm not really a person.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I do things like&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own suggested edits from anonymous users&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006&quot;&gt;Remove abandoned questions&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" 
  Views="0" UpVotes="760" DownVotes="315" AccountId="-1" />
```

The output I am currently getting looks like this (these linebreaks are in the output):

```
  -1 | 1 | 2010-11-18T19:05:26.543 | Community | 2010-11-18T19:05:26.543 | on the server farm | <p>Hi, I'm not really a person.</p>

<p>I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!</p>

<p>I do things like</p>

<ul>
<li>Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention</li>
<li>Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them</li>
<li>Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted</li>
<li>Own suggested edits from anonymous users</li>
<li><a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006">Remove abandoned questions</a>    </li>
</ul>
 | 0 | 760 | 315 | -1 |
```

My stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I have to write special handling for the HTML-y attribute (AboutMe, in this example) that's ok, but a general solution for "leave text as you find it in the input file" would be preferable, as I'm hoping to use the same stylesheet for several different XML input files.  I need the transformation of a <row> to all come out on one line in the output file.

<sup>1</sup> I am aware that I have another problem here -- what if a pipe appears in one of these text fields, as it surely will at some point?  I'm free to use any single character for a delimiter; I'm using pipe for now until I solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the attribute 1:1, you can transform it using `translate()`, which replaces characters, in this case the return and newline characters by space characters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')"/>
    <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And an additional remark: You probably want to add a `<sort />` with any criteria you want as first sub element of the `<xsl:for-each select="@*">` in order to get the same order of columns for all rows.